# 2 Textbox are not displaying in line

Tags: css, html, inline

I am trying to display 2 textbox in one line with their label.

I have used css for that but it's not working.

[jsfidle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kurbhatt/KgbwU/1/)

```
<div class="inq_form_label_prd">
Subject :
</div>
<div class="inq_form_content_prd">
    <input type="text" class="inq_txtbox_prd" name="inq_sub_msg">
</div>
<div class="inq_form_label_prd1">
    Subject :
</div>
<div class="inq_form_content_prd1">
    <input type="text" class="inq_txtbox_prd" name="inq_sub_msg">
</div>
```

CSS :

```
  .inq_form_label_prd
    {
        line-height: 28px;
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        color: #666;
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-left:0px;
    }
    .inq_form_content_prd
    {
        margin-left: 130px;
        line-height: 28px;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bolder;
    }
    .inq_form_label_prd1
    {
        line-height: 28px;
        float: left;
        width: 120px;
        font-weight: bolder;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 10px;
        color: #666;
        margin-top:5px;
        margin-left:200px;
    }
    .inq_form_content_prd1
    {
        margin-left: 390px;
        line-height: 28px;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bolder;
    }
```

Any suggestion, why it's not displaying inline.
I want 2 textbox and labels inline.
and next 2 in new line and so forth.

Thank You.

Comment: Any reason for not using the label tag? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Comment: @wickywills - No there's no reason but I want some proper format of specific size that's why I have used this one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jVaK5/)

You can make things simple.

```
<div class="block">
    <div>Subject
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>Subject
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
    <div>Subject
        <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div>Subject
        <input type="text">
    </div>
</div>

CSS

div {
    display: inline;
}
.block{
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Awesome anup bhai... so short and sweet.

Comment: Haa, aapke liye. Hum to abhi naye hai so tough lagta hai abhi. bat aapke jaise logo ka saath raha to sikh jayenge.

Comment: @user3145373 anup toh bhai master hai

Comment: @Anup - Anup sir, I have imported 2 css files so it's overwrite one. so how to give priority to it specific css ?

Comment: Priority can be set within Styles by giving `!important` at the end. e.g. `float: left!important;`

Comment: <span> is very much like a <div> element, but <div> is a block-level element whereas a <span> is an inline element.

[<span>: The Content Span element - HTML: HyperText Markup Language | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span)

Answer (score 2):

1. div tags are needed to change into span
2. remove float and margin properies;
3. wrap two blocks in two div tags

   [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/KgbwU/8/)

   ```
   <div>
   <span class="inq_form_label_prd">Subject :
   </span>
   <span class="inq_form_content_prd">
       <input type="text" class="inq_txtbox_prd" style="margin-top: 5px;" id="inq_sub_msg" name="inq_sub_msg" />
   </span>

   <span class="inq_form_label_prd1">Subject :
   </span>
   <span class="inq_form_content_prd1">
       <input type="text" class="inq_txtbox_prd" style="margin-top: 5px;" id="inq_sub_msg" name="inq_sub_msg" />
   </span>
   </div>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The `<div>` tags are displayed as `block`, for change this comportment add in your CSS `display: inline;` on each one of them you want to become on the same line.

Note : you could also use *inline-block*, have a try.

Answer (score 1):

i suggest you wrap the left part of each line in a div with "left-part" class, and the right part in a div with "right-part" class, and in css give each one the float:left/right;

```
.left-part {
    float: left;
}
.right-part {
    float: right;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DfPr5/